# DataGridView Place a frozen column to the far right

Tags: winforms, datagridview, .net-2.0

I have a DataGridView in a WinForms 2.0 App that has a lot of columns, enough that even when maximized the user has to scroll to see all columns.  The far right column is a delete button.  We want to always display the delete button without the user having to horizontally scroll.

When I try setting `column.Frozen = true;` it removes my horizontal scrollbar and makes all of the previous columns frozen.  According to [Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=117002&wa=wsignin1.0) this is by design.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: i'm having the same issue. i'm looking into it, i'll let you know if i find anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug report for VS 2005: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=117002&wa=wsignin1.0#

It looks like Microsoft doesnt care to correct the issue. "By design"? What a joke.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 var cols = dcols.ToArray();//dcols is the DataGridViewColumn List wait to add to DataGridView
    if (cols.Last().Frozen)
    {
        _this.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
        cols = cols.Reverse().ToArray();
    } 
    _this.Columns.AddRange(cols);
    //Note that DataGridView does not allow freezing on both sides at the same time, or freezing some columns in the middle.
```

You will have a problem. The scrollbar will be positioned to the far right. Then, you can try the code below:

```
//OnDataBindingComplete
        if (this.Columns.Count > 0)
            this.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = this.Columns.Count - 1;
```